# Add sequence in lapply R

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, lapply

I have created a function that I run using `lapply` and a list called `Path`:

```
CheckPath <- function(Path) {

  if (file.exists(Path)) {
    for (i in seq_along(Path)){
      cat(noquote(paste0('\nThe product is present. It can be found in the following path: \n\n', i, Path, '\n\n')))
      }
  } else {
    cat('\nThe product could not be found \n')
    stop()
  }
}

# Run the CheckPath function with Path as input
OutputPath <- lapply(Path, CheckPath)
```

Where `Path` is a list with absolute paths to some files

The desired output should be something like (if condition `TRUE`)

```
The product is present. It can be found in the following path 1 /my/path/
The product is present. It can be found in the following path 2 /my/path/
The product is present. It can be found in the following path 3 /my/path/
```

-- EDIT --

In the function, if I use

```
cat(noquote(paste0('\nThe product is present. It can be found in the following path: ', seq_along(Path), Path, )))
```

Gives me this output:

```
The product is present. It can be found in the following path: 

1/mypath/to/file


The product is present. It can be found in the following path:

1/mypath/to/file


The product is present. It can be found in the following path: 

1/mypath/to/file
```

This is very close to what I want but I need to have a sequence with `1` `2` `3`, etc.

Comment: Why you using `lapply()` when `test(Path)` will provide the expected output?

Comment: Why are you using `lapply` here? You don't seem to use the variable `var1` that you pass to the `test` function at all. It will return the same thing no matter what you pass in. I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: `Path <- c("test1", "test2", "test3"); paste("This is the", seq_along(Path), "text")`

Comment: @sindri_baldur I have edited the question with the actuall code and not a dummy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try the following code to get your desired results.

```
path <-list("text1","text2","text3")
lapply(path,function(x){paste("This is the",which(path==x),x)})
```

Comment: Great solution with 'which' and great contribution. Hope you will find this platform useful